# ImportError: No module named _clock (Windows 10)

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I tried to run a Kivy example from its github [repository](https://github.com/kivy/kivy), but I had an error. The console shows me this:

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in C:\Users\gg_gi\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-06-29_63.txt
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] Python: v2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[WARNING] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING] stderr:   File "D:/Kivy/kivy/examples/demo/showcase/main.py", line 29, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:     from kivy.app import App
[WARNING] stderr:   File "D:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\app.py", line 319, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
[WARNING] stderr:   File "D:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\base.py", line 29, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:     from kivy.clock import Clock
[WARNING] stderr:   File "D:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\clock.py", line 234, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:     from kivy._clock import CyClockBase, ClockEvent
[WARNING] stderr: **ImportError: No module named _clock**
```

Comment: It sounds like kivy isn't compiled properly.

Comment: Did you compile it, or just downloaded and tried to run? Seems like the second case.

Comment: Look [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4412#issuecomment-228455735).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for run examples kivy, I've just copy whatever example kivy, then I installed kivy 1.9.1 (current release) on my computer, so I ran the example without any problem. I think the development version has problems in windows.

Answer (score 0):

In the https://github.com/kivy/kivy/commit/feea3fc426882f11c83bf478b8712d3f9cbea842
the file of _clock.pyx is updated 8 days ago. Commit these changes into your _clock.py kivy module. 
Hope this works.

Comment: I don't think so, because I cloned the project today so I have these changes in my local repository.